# Complex query with loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

This current code is working :

```
  app.models.AvionPiloteAutorisation.find({
    "where": {
      "idAvion": avion.idAvion,
      "or": [{
        "dateExpiration": {
          gt: Date.now()
        }
      }, {
        "dateExpiration": null
      }],
      "dateSuppression": null
    },
    "include": {
      "relation": "pilote",
      "scope": {
        "include": {
          'piloteDisponibilite': {
            scope: {
              where: {
                "DateDebut": {
                  lt: Date.now()
                },
                "or": [{
                  "DateFin": {
                    gt: Date.now()
                  }
                }, {
                  "DateFin": null
                }]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But this :

```
function getAuthorizePilotes(avion, distance, idSociete, callbackA) {
  var tempsVolEstime = distance / avion.vitesseCroisiere;

  app.models.AvionPiloteAutorisation.find({
    "where": {
      "idAvion": avion.idAvion,
      "or": [{
        "dateExpiration": {
          gt: Date.now()
        }
      }, {
        "dateExpiration": null
      }],
      "dateSuppression": null
    },
    "include": {
      "relation": "pilote",
      "scope": {
        "include": {
          'utilisateur',
          'piloteDisponibilite': {
            scope: {
              where: {
                "DateDebut": {
                  lt: Date.now()
                },
                "or": [{
                  "DateFin": {
                    gt: Date.now()
                  }
                }, {
                  "DateFin": null
                }]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

fail. I'm trying to add a relation to Pilote. What am I doing wrong ?
How am I suppose to add a relation to this current code ?

I tried the "include": [ { ... } ] without success.

```
  app.models.AvionPiloteAutorisation.find({
    "where": {
      "idAvion": avion.idAvion,
      "or": [{
        "dateExpiration": {
          gt: Date.now()
        }
      }, {
        "dateExpiration": null
      }],
      "dateSuppression": null
    },
    "include": {
      "relation": "pilote",
      "scope": {
        "include": ["utilisateur"],
        "include": {
          relation: 'piloteDisponibilite',
          scope: {
            where: {
              "DateDebut": {
                lt: Date.now()
              },
              "or": [{
                "DateFin": {
                  gt: Date.now()
                }
              }, {
                "DateFin": null
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

No idea how it works. Not a clue in the official doc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it :

```
  app.models.AvionPiloteAutorisation.find({
    "where": {
      "idAvion": avion.idAvion,
      "or": [{
        "dateExpiration": {
          gt: Date.now()
        }
      }, {
        "dateExpiration": null
      }],
      "dateSuppression": null
    },
    "include": {
      "relation": "pilote",
      "scope": {
        "include": ["utilisateur", 'piloteDisponibilite'],
        relation: 'piloteDisponibilite',
        scope: {
          where: {
            "DateDebut": {
              lt: Date.now()
            },
            "or": [{
              "DateFin": {
                gt: Date.now()
              }
            }, {
              "DateFin": null
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

We are suppose to specify the relationship with relation keyword outside of the include array.